# Why is there a limit on the number of counters allowed in a Hadoop map reduce job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, counter

I am using Hadoop map-reduce and got a CountersExceededException when I tried to programatically create many job counters.  I know that I can increase the number of counters that are allowed through the configuration files, but does anyone know:

a) why there is a limit on map-reduce counters

and

b) if it is a good/bad idea to increase the max number of map-reduce counters?

I am using hadoop 0.20.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the section on Counters in [this post](https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/apache-hadoop-best-practices-anti-patterns-465.html).

> ### Counters
>
> Counters represent global counters, defined either by the Map/Reduce framework or applications. Applications can define arbitrary Counters and update them in the map and/or reduce methods. These counters are then globally aggregated by the framework.
>
> Counters are appropriate for tracking few, important, global bits of information. They are definitely not meant to aggregate very fine-grained statistics of applications.
>   Counters are very expensive since the JobTracker has to maintain every counter of every map/reduce task for the entire duration of the application.

Comment: gotcha, "Counters are very expensive since the JobTracker has to maintain every counter of every map/reduce task for the entire duration of the application."  Thanks for the link

Comment: Dead link. A summary would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

> Just in case you want to up the maximum number of counters.

Last I saw the code, the maximum number of counters has been hard coded in the code and not configurable. Please check the [blog entry](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2011/12/limiting-usage-counters-in-hadoop.html) I have written some time back for more details and also go through the [latest code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/) to check if this has been modified to make it configurable.